# Adjust text underline leading

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I want to move the underline on a line of text down (away from the text), i,e. adjust the leading. 
But this doesn't work:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5.0f;

 NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Something"];
 [string addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
 [string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? The default rendering is terrible.